# Trying to write a code that goes from 10-1 and back

Tags: java

I am trying to write code that goes from 10-1 and back:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I cannot figure it out. I've got this so far:

```
package numbers;

class  Numbers {
   
 protected static Object Numbers;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        for(n=10; n>=0; n--) { //count BACKWARDS
            //if n <=0 n = 1
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, you’d probably want 2 for-loops. One to print backwards, like you have, and one to print forwards

Comment: You could also use one for loop like you have, but change the condition from n >= 0 to n >= -10, then in body of the loop print the Math.abs(n) value to achieve the sequence you wanted.

Comment: That's 10 to 0 and back, not 10 to 1 and back.

Comment: You can use IntStream like this : IntStream.rangeClosed(-10, 10)
           .forEach(i -> System.out.print(String.format("%s ",Math.abs(i))));

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `for` loops.

```
for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) System.out.println(i);
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.  Based on your expected output I presume you mean from ten to zero and back. Go from `-10 to 10 inclusive` and change the sign when `< 0`.

- uses the ternary operater `(?:)   (e.g) a ? b : c`
- given a conditional, if `a` is true, do `b`, else to `c`

```
for (int i = -10; i <= 10 ; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d ",i < 0 ? -i : i);
}
```

Prints

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

You can also change the print statement to to use the absolute value.

```
System.out.printf("%d ",Math.abs(i));
```

But here is the fun one. A recursive solution. Just not very efficient. It keeps printing the adjusted value and calling itself until the condition is met, then returns and prints values on the call stack in ascending order.

```
tenToOneToTen(10);

public static void tenToOneToTen(int i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        System.out.printf("%d ",i);
        tenToOneToTen(i-1);
    } 
    System.out.printf("%d ", i);
}
```